# Real Analysis: Uniform Continuity Homework

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-continuity

Show that the function $f(x) = \frac{1
}x$
is uniformly continuous on the interval
$[1, 2]$ using only the definition.

My Approach: For all $\epsilon > 0$ there exits $\delta > 0$ such that if $|x − y| < \delta$ then $|f(x) − f(y)| < \epsilon$.

So $|\frac{1}x - \frac{1}y| = |\frac{y-x}{xy}| < \delta|\frac{1}{xy}|$

Since $x,y \in [1,2]$, then we may say $\delta|\frac{1}{xy}| < \delta$ (since the highest $\frac{1}{xy}$ can be is then $\frac{1}{1*1}$.

So set $\epsilon= \delta$, and the proof is done. I hope :)

Comment: Looks good to me!

Answer (score 1):

The idea is fine, but you need to adjust a few things. The point of an $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ proof is that you need to tell me, given some $\varepsilon>0$, who the $\delta$ is. Saying "there exists $\delta>0$" can never be a proof on itself, unless you are using some previous result.

What you have shown is that it is enough to take $\delta=\varepsilon$.

Comment: So would it be more appropriate to say something like "Let $\epsilon > 0$" to start the proof?

Comment: Should I also state that I would assume $|x-y| < \delta$

Comment: Yes. When you write the proof, you say "Let $\varepsilon>0$", and then you say who $\delta$ should be. Then comes the estimate that if $|x-y|<\delta$, then $|f(x)-f(y)|<\varepsilon$.

Comment: Thank you very much sir! This is my first proofs class, so I'm not too familiar with the language yet. Thanks again!

Comment: No problem. You'll get the hang of it very soon.

Comment: One last comment. I notice that you have not accepted a single answer to your questions yet. The way this site works, you would usually upvote answers that are useful to you, and also often accept the one that suits you best.